# How would I perform multiple unpivots within one query in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have two queries that each perform an unpivot and the result comes out looking as I would intend for each, I would like to put these together into one select query.

Original Table:

| CCN | C_FORECAST_YEAR | CUSTOMER | ITEM | REVISION | MARKET | C_SALFOR_RVRT | COMM_PERCENT | CONTRACT_PRICE1 | CONTRACT_PRICE2 | CONTRACT_PRICE3 | CONTRACT_PRICE4 | CONTRACT_PRICE5 | CONTRACT_PRICE6 | CONTRACT_PRICE7 | CONTRACT_PRICE8 | CONTRACT_PRICE9 | CONTRACT_PRICE10 | CONTRACT_PRICE11 | CONTRACT_PRICE12 | QTY1 | QTY2 | QTY3 | QTY4 | QTY5 | QTY6 | QTY7 | QTY8 | QTY9 | QTY10 | QTY11 | QTY12 | ACT_PRICE1 | ACT_PRICE2 | ACT_PRICE3 | ACT_PRICE4 | ACT_PRICE5 | ACT_PRICE6 | ACT_PRICE7 | ACT_PRICE8 | ACT_PRICE9 | ACT_PRICE10 | ACT_PRICE11 | ACT_PRICE12 | ACT_QTY1 | ACT_QTY2 | ACT_QTY3 | ACT_QTY4 | ACT_QTY5 | ACT_QTY6 | ACT_QTY7 | ACT_QTY8 | ACT_QTY9 | ACT_QTY10 | ACT_QTY11 | ACT_QTY12 | LAST_ARCHIVE_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023 1030 | 6A4R17 | ADCCNENGR | 2.000 | 2.390000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 19202.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | NULL |
| 1 | 2023 1030 | 6A4R19 | DCCENG | 80 | 2.000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 0.000000 | 1.500000 | 0.000000 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | NULL |

Query 1:

```
Select UNPVT.C_FORECAST_YEAR, UNPVT.CUSTOMER, UNPVT.ITEM, UNPVT.C_SALFOR_RVRT,[CONTRACT_MONTH], CONTRACT_PRICE from
    (SELECT C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER,ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,CONTRACT_PRICE1,CONTRACT_PRICE2,CONTRACT_PRICE3,CONTRACT_PRICE4,CONTRACT_PRICE5,CONTRACT_PRICE6,CONTRACT_PRICE7,CONTRACT_PRICE8,CONTRACT_PRICE9,CONTRACT_PRICE10,CONTRACT_PRICE11,CONTRACT_PRICE12 FROM C_SALFOR)P
UNPIVOT 
    (CONTRACT_PRICE FOR [CONTRACT_MONTH] in (CONTRACT_PRICE1,CONTRACT_PRICE2,CONTRACT_PRICE3,CONTRACT_PRICE4,CONTRACT_PRICE5,CONTRACT_PRICE6,CONTRACT_PRICE7,CONTRACT_PRICE8,CONTRACT_PRICE9,CONTRACT_PRICE10,CONTRACT_PRICE11,CONTRACT_PRICE12))AS UNPVT
WHERE UNPVT.C_FORECAST_YEAR = '2023'
```

Results:

| C_FORECAST_YEAR | CUSTOMER | ITEM | C_SALFOR_RVRT | CONTRACT_MONTH | CONTRACT_PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1030 | 6A4R17 |  | CONTRACT_PRICE1 | 8.390000 |
| 2023 | 1030 | 6A4R17 |  | CONTRACT_PRICE2 | 0.000000 |

Query 2:

```
Select C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER, ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,[QTY_MONTH], QTY from
    (SELECT C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER,ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,QTY1,QTY2,QTY3,QTY4,QTY5,QTY6,QTY7,QTY8,QTY9,QTY10,QTY11,QTY12 FROM C_SALFOR)Q
UNPIVOT 
    (QTY FOR [QTY_MONTH] in (QTY1,QTY2,QTY3,QTY4,QTY5,QTY6,QTY7,QTY8,QTY9,QTY10,QTY11,QTY12))AS UNPVT2
WHERE C_FORECAST_YEAR = '2023'
```

Results:

| C_FORECAST_YEAR | CUSTOMER | ITEM | C_SALFOR_RVRT | QTY_MONTH | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1030 | 6A4R17 |  | QTY1 | 19008 |
| 2023 | 1030 | 6A4R17 |  | QTY2 | 00000 |

Desired result:

| C_FORECAST_YEAR | CUSTOMER | ITEM | C_SALFOR_RVRT | CONTRACT_MONTH | CONTRACT_PRICE | QTY_MONTH | QTY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | 1030 | 6A4R17 |  | CONTRACT_PRICE1 | 8.390000 | QTY1 | 19008 |
| 2023 | 1030 | 6A4R17 |  | CONTRACT_PRICE2 | .000000 | QTY2 | 00000 |

Comment: please add also the original table with data and tag your database system

Comment: Thanks nbk, I am hoping I did that correctly

Comment: GPT-4 answer, good?: SELECT 
  C_FORECAST_YEAR, 
  CUSTOMER, 
  ITEM, 
  C_SALFOR_RVRT, 
  v.CONTRACT_MONTH, 
  v.CONTRACT_PRICE, 
  v.QTY_MONTH, 
  v.QTY
FROM 
  C_SALFOR
CROSS APPLY 
(
    VALUES 
        ('1', CONTRACT_PRICE1, QTY1),
       ...
        ('12', CONTRACT_PRICE12, QTY12)
) AS v(CONTRACT_MONTH, CONTRACT_PRICE, QTY)
WHERE C_FORECAST_YEAR = '2023'

Comment: The root of the problem is that your table is not properly normalized. You have violated 1NF with what is known as repeating groups. That would be better suited as two tables.

Comment: I agree with you Sean, I am using this to populate another table where it would be normalized so that I can report from it. Unfortunately I don't have control to change this system.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do the unpivot "manually":

```
with data as (
    select C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER, ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,
        case n when 1  then CONTRACT_PRICE1
               when 2  then CONTRACT_PRICE2
               when 3  then CONTRACT_PRICE3
               when 4  then CONTRACT_PRICE4
               when 5  then CONTRACT_PRICE5
               when 6  then CONTRACT_PRICE6
               when 7  then CONTRACT_PRICE7
               when 8  then CONTRACT_PRICE8
               when 9  then CONTRACT_PRICE9
               when 10 then CONTRACT_PRICE10
               when 11 then CONTRACT_PRICE11
               when 12 then CONTRACT_PRICE12
        end as CONTRACT_MONTH,
        case n when 1  then QTY1
               when 2  then QTY2
               when 3  then QTY3
               when 4  then QTY4
               when 5  then QTY5
               when 6  then QTY6
               when 7  then QTY7
               when 8  then QTY8
               when 9  then QTY9
               when 10 then QTY10
               when 11 then QTY11
               when 12 then QTY12
         end as QTY_MONTH
    from C_SALFOR cross apply
        (values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12)) as u(n)
    where C_FORECAST_YEAR = '2023' -- are you sure this is a character string?
)
select * from data
-- is there potential for missing values/incomplete years?
where QTY_MONTH is not null or CONTRACT_MONTH is not null;
```

You could also capture the values within the `cross apply` as:

```
(values (CONTRACT_PRICE1, QTY1),
        (CONTRACT_PRICE2, QTY2),
        -- ...
        (CONTRACT_PRICE12, QTY12)
) as u(CONTRACT_MONTH, QTY_MONTH)
```

This would only work on SQL Server. The first version is a bit more portable/classic SQL. There are other ways to generate the list of numbers from 1 to 12.

Comment: Thank you shawnt00 I was not familiar with this approach, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can cross aplly the second unpivot as subquery

```
Select UNPVT.C_FORECAST_YEAR, UNPVT.CUSTOMER, UNPVT.ITEM, UNPVT.C_SALFOR_RVRT,[CONTRACT_MONTH], CONTRACT_PRICE,unpvt2.QTY_MONTH, unpvt2.QTY from
    (SELECT C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER,ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,CONTRACT_PRICE1,CONTRACT_PRICE2,CONTRACT_PRICE3,CONTRACT_PRICE4,CONTRACT_PRICE5,CONTRACT_PRICE6,CONTRACT_PRICE7,CONTRACT_PRICE8,CONTRACT_PRICE9,CONTRACT_PRICE10,CONTRACT_PRICE11,CONTRACT_PRICE12 FROM C_SALFOR)P
UNPIVOT 
    (CONTRACT_PRICE FOR [CONTRACT_MONTH] in (CONTRACT_PRICE1,CONTRACT_PRICE2,CONTRACT_PRICE3,CONTRACT_PRICE4,CONTRACT_PRICE5,CONTRACT_PRICE6,CONTRACT_PRICE7,CONTRACT_PRICE8,CONTRACT_PRICE9,CONTRACT_PRICE10,CONTRACT_PRICE11,CONTRACT_PRICE12))AS UNPVT
    CROSS APPLY (Select C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER, ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,[QTY_MONTH], QTY from
    (SELECT C_FORECAST_YEAR, CUSTOMER,ITEM, C_SALFOR_RVRT,QTY1,QTY2,QTY3,QTY4,QTY5,QTY6,QTY7,QTY8,QTY9,QTY10,QTY11,QTY12 FROM C_SALFOR)Q
UNPIVOT 
    (QTY FOR [QTY_MONTH] in (QTY1,QTY2,QTY3,QTY4,QTY5,QTY6,QTY7,QTY8,QTY9,QTY10,QTY11,QTY12))AS UNPVT2
WHERE C_FORECAST_YEAR = '2023'
) unpvt2
WHERE UNPVT.C_FORECAST_YEAR = '2023'
```